# Overcoming weak area in a interview

Tags: software-industry, job-search, career-development

In interviews, many companies want you to be a guru of something, while in software industry knowing one thing is not considered good, whereas someone who is fullstack is considered good. While this may count as a weakness, how can one overcome it to tell the person interviewing you that you can overcome if given a job, and question to ask them in return that might make you sound a strong candidate.

Comment: I don't think there is an answerable question here.  If you are not getting interviews, then you need to look at your CV and see _why_ you are not getting past the first screening.  Unfortunately your question as is reads more as a rant following on from your various other questions on the site here, and will likely be closed unless you can distil it down to a direct, answerable question.

Comment: If you can't find a job in your preferred field right now, you might want to take *any* job that will pay the bills and afford you some time to work on building your development skills. Maybe start working with some open source project.

Comment: This is enough of a different question you may be better off asking it as a different question assuming this does not get reopened quickly.

Comment: I *think* that this is now no longer a duplicate but I can't actually tell what the question is...